# passing uiimageview as a parameter in NStimer selector?

Tags: iphone

i created a function onTimer passing it a uiimageview parameter...but when i call this function in a NStimer call as shown below i get a syntax error?? is there any other way around it??

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:image) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your Image View through `userInfo`.

Using @`selector(onTimer:image:)` will not help you since you can't specify what it should pass into the second parameter.